# Jennair JES9900 custom infinite switch delivering full power at all settings

Tags: switch

The W10185286 infinite switch on my Jennair JES9900 has been a recurring issue over the years.
The normal failure is the loud clicking and loss of power.
But I recently replace the switch after such a failure, and although it appeared to be ok for a day, it now heats the inner ring fully when turned one way, and heats the whole ring fully in the other direction. There is no intensity control.
Measuring the output voltage from the switch confirms that it is delivering 230v on any settings. So the switch appears to be defective now.
I’ve have another new switch ($200) but am reluctant to install it in case something is destroying the switches.
The element shows about 25 ohms on each section. The thermocouple measures 1k and does respond to heating.
Based on a similar post I’ve purchased a megger to ensure that there is not a high voltage short somewhere.
Looking for guidance on specific test points for the megger. Thank you

Comment: Where are you are measuring voltage? These switches do not reduce the voltage. They are electromechanical devices that oscillate between full L1 to L2 (240 V) voltage and zero. AFIK only one of the lines is interrupted but that reduces the current to zero in the OFF phase. They supply only L1 to L2 voltage in the ON phase of a duty cycle. The heat output is determined by the fraction of the cycle that the full voltage is ON. If the burner is giving high power when the switch is on a low setting then either the switch is faulty or it is connected incorrectly.

Comment: Our GE electric range does not have any "double burners". Our burners have only an L1 and L2 connection at the burner. At our switches there are 5 connections L1, L2, S1, S2, P). L1 and L2 are the incoming hot lines. S1 and S2 (or H1 and H2) are the switched lines to the burner.  P is for the indicator light. In a double burner I think there would be one more switched line. Do either of the elements of this double burner work correctly?

Comment: Thank you Jim. You make an excellent point about duty cycle. I’m measuring at H1/H2, the wires which go to the hot plate . There’s a 3rd wire because it’s a dual element. With my voltmeter the voltage looks completely steady . When set to min I would have thought the meter would show a drop, or at least some variation due to the low duty cycle. I looked at the patent for the switch US 6,951, 997 and the min setting duty cycle is only a few %. Would that not register as an effective lower voltage on the meter (depends on time constant of the meter I guess)? Many thanks for your help Jim

Comment: For comparison make the same measurements on a burner which is working. FYI 25 ohm gives a 2300 W burner at 240 V.  (The resistance will rise as the temperature of the burner rises so 2300 W is a slight overestimate of the power rating.) This is a common power level category. It appears your elements are OK.

Comment: What thermocouple? If this burner has a temperature control circuit with a thermocouple, then that circuit may be causing a malfunction.

Comment: Yes Jim, this fancy switch includes 2 terminals which go to a thermocouple directly under the glass. It’s the only burner on this Jennair that has this complicated feedback feature. That’s why I mentioned that it’s resistance is measuring ok, and is responding to heat changes.  Over-engineered system with multiple possible failure points. One of the options I’m considering is reworking with a simpler system ( like the other dual burner on the stove), but that’s a lot of work too. Plan A is to just  megger test the load and then try the new switch, hoping that it doesn’t blow again.

Comment: These switches might be hard to test unless they are in the circuit. These dissipate a small amount of power through a bimetallic strip which breaks (or makes) the power circuit by curving when the strip reaches a certain temperature. Evidently they come in two types "voltage sensitive or dependent" and "current sensitive or dependent".  This is based on a reference in the technical paperwork accompanying our 30-year-old GE range,  All of them may now be one of the types.

Comment: BTW the temperature sensor is possibly not a thermocouple but rather a thermistor, i.e., a resistor whose resistance varies strongly with temperature. The thermistor is in a circuit such that either the current through the thermistor or the voltage across it is an approximately linear function of the temperature of the thermistor. It is possible that the high temperature of the surface unit requires a "thermocouple" but pretty sure the oven temp sensor element is a thermistor.

Comment: This one is a bit more sophisticated based on the patent. The user input (knob settings) is the input signal to a digital board which contains lookup tables to instruct the relays on the duty cycle appropriate to that setting. I kept an old oscilloscope for 15 years and then sold it last summer. I knew it was a mistake to get rid of it.

Comment: This opens up the possibility of a fault in a circcuit board. The information about the presence of these circuit boards shold be edited into the question.   Are all the surface burners on the same board? Or are there separate small boards for each burner?

Comment: The switch itself contains a small circuit board Jim.  It’s an integral part of the design. I don’t think this site allows images to be uploaded, otherwise I could show a photo.  So the over-engineered switch has multiple potential failure modes, including damage to components on that board. Since the switch only lasted a day (similar to another thread on this same topic) I’m worried that a defect elsewhere in the load has fried the new switch. That’s why my next step is megger testing of the heating element.

Comment: This site does allow uploading images or at least uploading the link to an image hosting site. The old electromechanical switches are much cheaper. It seems this Jennair 9900 is a repair expense trap. Perhaps you could contact a Jennair expert or at least someone who is familiar with the failure modes of this family of products.

Comment: Does the circuit board have a wiper that moves across contacts on the board? Is the heat adjustment continuous or is it discrete settings? Is the replacement switch that went bad OEM or aftermarket?

Comment: Hi Jim. There is a wiper that runs over a couple of rows of copper pads connected to surface mounted resistor. So the input to the circuitry is on discrete values. If you are interested you can google US 6,951, 997 which explains how this is supposed to work.  My insulation tester arrived from Amazon, and was a complete dud. I knew the price was too low. So I’m back to hunting for a used megger before I dare plug in another $200 switch ( these switches are all Whirlpool OEM)

Comment: By "megger" do you mean an ohmmeter? I doubt than a measurement of reistance  (ohm scale measurement) would reveal anything. You would need specifics on how to test the circuit board and discrete elements if there are any. Continuity vs open circuit results can be revealing for the normal, standard "infinite switch" , but you would need to know how this Jennair switch works to test it. Do power wires go directly from this switch to the heating element or is this switch signalling to another element? Are all the switches in this Jennair 9900 this type or is this the only one?

Comment: No Jim, a megger specifically tests for leakage paths at high voltage (eg 500vdc ). A regular ohm meter only uses 9v so readings look normal even if there is a high voltage leakage path. The combination of analogue and digital circuits limits how much I can test. For example the 48v dc that triggers the duty cycle relay is controlled by a transistor which is switched by the digital control circuit. So many possible failure points in this thing.

Comment: I have heard of these high voltage leakage testers being used on resistive loads such as in-floor resistance heating coils, but would you use that on a circuit board without a specific protocol?

Comment: Not on the circuit board, no. That would destroy it. I have the load side isolated. I’m simply testing the wires and the heating element.

Comment: Possibly the temperature sensing circuit is incorrectly signaling to the switch that the burner is below set temperature. Or the temperature sensing circuit is faulty and is over or under loading the switch causing the switch to fail after a certain period of use.

Comment: So the megger test on the wiring showed no leakage paths , so I went ahead and installed the second new switch. Measuring ac voltage between red (H1) and H2A & H2B (yellow and brown) still showed constant 240v at all settings without the hot plate connected ( which still seems odd when the duty cycle is only a few %). I then connected just the temp sensor and heated it with a lighter. Sure enough, the voltage cut out when hot, and came back as it cooled. So the temperature sensor seems to be functioning, but the power level appears to be binary ( not what this switch is supposed to do)

Comment: Went ahead and connected everything up.  The ring comes on full blast and kicks off at temperature. So the lack of visible duty-cycle modulation is a mystery. That is supposed to be the main feature of this $200 switch.  The replaced switch would not click off at all, so I’m one step ahead after all this. But still perplexed by the lack of apparent duty cycle control.

Comment: So are you saying the burner is working correctly or is it not? Are you saying that the burner is either full on or it is off? This is a double burner. Is one ring of the burner working correctly and the other is not?

Comment: Are you testing the operation of the switch to this double burner with a pan on the burner with water in it?

Comment: It’s a double burner. Turn to left to turn on inner ring. Turn to right for both ring . In either case , a low setting is supposed to signal the electronics to pull a low duty cycle profile from memory to power the ring. Then the temperature sensor should override it once temperature is achieved.  So with the exception perhaps of initial heat up, I’d expect to see little glow at min heat (few %) duty cycle. What I actually see is full glow cycling controlled only by the temp sensor signalling on/off. No evidence of different duty cycles being deployed. So it’s usable.

Comment: But all the fancy electronic duty cycle control does not appear to be effective.  
Wish I’d kept my oscilloscope so I could actually see any evidence of duty cycle changes. Visually based on glow levels, and voltage probing, it appears that the on/off heat sensor at the ring is the sole source of control. (Same result with or without pan of water)

Comment: Does this "on/off heat sensor at the ring" thermostatically control the power output or is it only a shut-off for overheating? Will this surface element keep a pan of water at a simmer or slow boil? Either as a small inner or full double burner?

Comment: The heater assembly contains 2 separate temperature sensitive devices. There is the normal over-temperature cut out sensor (looks like a white ceramic tube extending to the centre of the ring. This had a metal rod which expands to cut off the power in an serious over-temp condition.  But mine has a second thermal sensor probe which feeds a resistance reading back to the the infamously over-engineered switch.  This is the probe I'm referring to. It appears to be doing all the controlling, causing a binary full-on/full-off "control" .

Comment: It does the job . Water simmers. But this particular heater plate on the Jennair is advertised as a "custom" control ring, with the ability to hold temperature within a much better tolerance than a simple on-off thermal switch.  I don't think its operating as it should. but without an oscilloscope, I cant prove it.

Comment: Can this burner hold the contents of a pan below the boiling point? Can it keep something at say 200 deg F or 190 F?

Comment: Good suggestion. I'll gather some data and see how stable it is.